# OpenGL - How to dissolve between two consecutive frames that are drawn to screen frame buffer

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have photo editing view that displays an OpenGL ES 2.0 view.
I want to give the effect of dissolve between the original image and the filtered image. is it possible using OpenGL?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You should look into alpha mapping and multitexturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to be able to bind these two different images as separate textures to be fed into a dissolve shader. Once you have those, you could use a fragment shader like the following:

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
 uniform lowp float mixturePercent;

 void main()
 {
    lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate);

    gl_FragColor = mix(textureColor, textureColor2, mixturePercent);
 }
```

where `inputImageTexture` and `inputImageTexture2` are your textures to blend, and the mixturePercent is the degree to which the second image overrides the first.

The above was drawn from my [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) open source framework, which might make your image filtering job a little easier. You could provide your initial image as a GPUImagePicture, add a target of a GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter to that, add another target to the GPUImagePicture for the filter (or chain of filters) you'd like to apply, and then add a target of the same GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter for the last filter there. By varying the `mix` on the blend, you can dissolve between the original image and the filtered one.

GPUImage uses OpenGL ES 2.0 behind the scenes, but it abstracts away some of the direct interaction with OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you will need some threshold function of time and pixel factor.
To describe the approach more detaily we need to know what would be pixel factor (alpha channel, luminance, third texture...).
Take a look at [this](http://mtheorygame.com/2011/09/17/dissolve-shader-documentation/) example.